# Spring boot: Override property value

Tags: spring-boot

Into my `application-pre.properties` file there's coded this property:

```
scheduler.url-backoffice=http://${BACKOFFICE_SERVICE}:8080
```

In order to fill it, I'm using `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=scheduler-config.properties`.

`scheduler-config.properties`:

```
BACKOFFICE_SERVICE=localhost
scheduler.url-backoffice=http://localhost:8081
```

I need to set `BACKOFFICE_SERVICE` property, otherwise spring doesn't start. So, it means that `scheduler.url-backoffice` comes to `http://localhost:8080`.

I 've added another line after that in order override its value.

My surprise is its value is not changed. I mean, `scheduler.url-backoffice`'s value is `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8081`.

**I'm not able to change `application-pre.properties` content file.**

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple application properties files.
One can ship in the jar;
this contains the defaults.
For me, defaults translates to either the prod values,
if there is only one set of prod values,
or the developer local values (which should cause failures in production).

The second file contains the environment specific property values that
override the defaults.

You must change your startup values to achieve this.
Here is an example:
`-Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--spring.config.additional-location=scheduler-config.properties,local-scheduler-config.properties`

*Edit:*  in response to "still not working".

It seems like you need much more than the "simple" approach I described above.
For that,
check out section **24. Externalized Configuration** in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-application).

There are many techniques to override configuration values;
all are covered in the reference guide.